# In a machine using 16 bit addresses and page size is 512 addresses, what's the maximum size for a process that executes?

Tags: process, paging, processor, memory-address, process-management

Since its `16 bit` addresses and page size of `512` addresses, I think that makes the page offset 9 bits (512 is 2<sup>9</sup>) and the number of pages is 2<sup>16</sup> - 2<sup>9</sup> = 2<sup>7</sup>. What is the maximum size for a process that executes on this machine without the use of page demanding? In a process of size `4,535 words`, what is the total memory that must be allocated to the program and how much fragmentation is there? 
Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Is the maximum size of the process 2^16, or 65,536 words? And for the process size of 4535, would the memory needed be 4608 (512 * 9) with fragmentation of 73 (4608 - 4535)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum size of the process 2^16, or 65,536 words.

For the process size of 4535, the memory needed be 4608 (512 * 9) with fragmentation of 73 (4608 - 4535).